# Binary linear programming. Am I doing it right?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, constraints, binary-programming

I have been working on a problem for a week and I have already chosen a path to advance on. I would give a brief introduction about my problem and then put forward my question.

For a road network, there are 10 intersections, each intersection has 10 Signal plans (Signal plans have red and green time for every direction). I have to choose a single signal plan from each of the ten intersections such that the resulting combination would give least stops (I would get the number of stops from the model I am using) . The main condition is the selected Signal program should have same cycle time(time for which signal program runs)

https://www.mediafire.com/?5660zxbo7u65uvm

After going through a lot of litearture I finally chose binary mixed integer programming for my model. I set almost all constraints but the major problem is setting a constraint for "equal cycle time' 
What kind of constraint could be used in such case?

Comment: Please add a picture / diagram of the network to your question.

Comment: @unseen_rider how could I do that?

Comment: One way is to take a photo of it, upload it to a site like mediafire, copy the link to it, and add the link to your question.

Comment: Thanks @unseen_rider!!!! here it is:  https://www.mediafire.com/?5660zxbo7u65uvm

Hope it works :)

Comment: Ok please upvote on comments you find helpful.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add the tag "operations-research". This may attract more attention.